# udev/dpkg error

Tags: ssh, dpkg, udev

I'm getting this strange output every time I try to execute a command through SSH on my VPS (Ubuntu Server 15.04) which doesn not allow me to install anything. Any suggestions ?

```
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
    dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
     systemd depends on udev; however:
      Package udev is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     udev
     systemd
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `/var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst` for editing. Then comment `invoke-rc.d udev restart` line. Save and close.
2. Run

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```

I had similar case before: [How does apt-get purge work? Why it couldn't remove broken package in one pass?](https://askubuntu.com/a/687321/26246)