# Apport aptget returning E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dpkg, apport

There seems to be a lot of question like this but none have solved my problem. I was trying to install `libprotobuf-dev` and `protobuf-compiler` packages. but couldn't install that. got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libprotobuf-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3).
protobuf-compiler is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.14) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

One of the solutions told me to move all apport related files from the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` into `/tmp`, that also didn't work I get the same error. I have spend several hours behind this error. Couldn't get it sorted. Is there any possible solution?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/790005/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code1/827344 and update your question

Comment: @Panther: Heh, I was looking for this exact answer and couldn't find it among those listed in my profile. Sadly I cannot flag it as a duplicate because of the lack of votes or accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinstall pycompile, try this

```
sudo apt purge apport # purge apport
sudo apt reinstall python-minimal # reinstall python-minimal
sudo apt install apport # install apport
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f # resume last APT session
```

purging apport makes sure that you can start a clean fresh installation of apport and re-install python-minimal installs pycompile, which is needed for apport

Comment: thanks, All I had to do was reinstall the python and install apport again.