# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade - mysql-server 8 not working

Tags: 20.04

I have undertaken an upgrade of our Ubuntu server from `18` to `20.04`.
During the installation I had no errors reported and, once completed, I was able to log onto the server directly (through PuTTY) and all seemed fine.

However, this server is used as our Moodle server and the website failed (refused to connect).

One of our technicians sent me the following information...

> On running the command `sudo systemctl start apache2`, we receive an error and prompt to run a status command.

> On running the status command `sudo systemctl status apache2`, the server confirms that the apache2 service is reporting a syntax error on line 140 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. By catting this file (or better, opening to edit via WinSCP) we can see that line 140 has command `IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load`.

> This command is attempting to import the `auto_ntlm_winbind` module, located at `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.so` which does not appear to exist. I've attempted to manually re-add the missing .so file but this has not changed the issue.

So, today I tried to reinstall Apache2. This flagged up that `mysql-server-8.0` was not working correctly.
So, I tried to repair `mysql-server-8.0` but to no avail. The reinstallation kept telling me that the error logs were in `/var/log/mysql/` but I cannot access this directory (`mysql`); permission denied (I have an admin user account and should have total control over the server). I have tried `chown` (with `sudo`) but still no luck.

The first error I spot with any of the alterations I have tried is:

```
2023-08-01T13:44:06.810792Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

If I run `systemctl status mysql.services` I get...

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2023-08-01 14:50:34 BST; 5s ago
    Process: 2814768 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2814779 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 9424)
     Memory: 278.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─2814779 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

And if I do `journalctl -xe` then everything it reports seems fine (all relevant services queued have been started).

Continuing with the error list I have I get...

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-08-01 14:44:18 BST; 34ms ago
    Process: 2812282 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2812304 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2812304 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, it appears that I cannot run Apache2 because mysql is not running, which is not running because mysql-server-8 is not running; but I seem to be chasing my tail here.

Many of the advice steps I find are about flushing the database and I do NOT want to do that!

Any help please?

Comment: I think you did forget the first step, which is "Make a backup, and check if the backup is OK"

Comment: Thank you so much for that comment; so helpful!
To set the record straight, I was assured that backups were in place but then, once undertaken, the assurance was less forthcoming.
I could spend far too much of my time trying to find out specifically whose fault it was and seek reprimand; or I could, instead, try to see if I can resolve the problem.
I opt for 2.

Comment: You do not need to reprimand anyone (except yourself). When you have a proper backup, you can revert to the original situation, en (try to) resolve the same problem again (and again)

Comment: You really have little idea.
I am not in a position to run the backups myself. I enquired if backups were being taken. I was assured they were. They were not.
Now, do you have any actual useful advice or do you wish to remain on that high and mighty platform offering unnecessary gems of 'wisdom' that simply show how little you know?

Comment: This (stackoverflow) question/answer might help, you only need to change 5.7 to 8.0, and I cannot give any guarantees. [dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (dependency problems)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446218/dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-dependency-problems). There is even an older q/a on askubuntu here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/789686/dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-configure